# Is it possible to use request.POST as a dictionary input?

Tags: python, django, forms, request

In my django project, I collect membership data by HTML form and insert them into the database. There are the code samples:

models.py

```
class member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py:

```
def manage(request):
    form_values = request.POST.copy()
    form_values.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken') # I don't need it.
    add_member = member(**form_values)
    add_member.save()
```

If HTML form input is: Rafi, Male, student

Database gets in list format: ['Rafi'], ['Male'], ['student']

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`.dict()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) method here:

```
def manage(request):
    form_values = request.POST.copy()
    form_values.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
    add_member = member(**form_values.dict())
    add_member.save()
```

If there are multiple values for the same key, it will take the last one.

That being said, it might be better to take a look at a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) to validate data and convert it to a model object. This basically does what you do here, except with proper validation, removing boilerplate code, and furthermore it will not use the other keys. If here a user would "*forge*" a POST request with extra key-value pairs, the server will raise a 500 error.

Comment: Just Worked! Thanks a lot. Need more time to better understand the method and alternatives. Thanks again.

Comment: I've a number input. In this case, the number is not being integer but string. What can i do to get as integer value.

Comment: @RafiSarker: normally that is not necessary. Normally the django ORM takes care about that when storing the values. You can use `x = int(y)` to convert a string `y` to an int `x` (given of course it is a string that contains a number).

Comment: django ORM didn't handled it actually :( . I had to do it through ` x = int(y)`. Did my job well. But I would be happy if I must not do this. Because I used `<input type='number'>` in the HTML form.